# ubuntu wsl не видит установленный php

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

Помогите пожалуйста в встроенном терминале windows выводится версия php при выполнение команды php -v но в терминале ubuntu не выводится

P.S установлен Windows 11

[image: слева встроенный терминал windows, справа терминал ubuntu wsl]

Comment: а вы не думали установить пхп в убунту?)) (там две строки с инструкциями даже есть, на вашем скрине)

Comment: попробовал но выдает error 404

Comment: бывает, но стоит таки установить пхп непосредственно в виртуальную машину, если хотите его использовать там

Comment: с этим разобрался. Но не подскажите как удалить эти версии ubuntu wsl которые отмечены на скриншоте https://prnt.sc/WE0PEzBC5UT8